# HANA Schema User and Role Security

Tags: sapui5, sap-cloud-platform, sap-web-ide

Not able to Grant the roles: Granted roles, System privileges, object privileges, etc to user ADMIN from security portal by Hana SYSTEM user so that ADMIN can create other users from an application developed using SAP HANA Cloud Platform.

Please let me know what roles need to be assigned by SYSTEM user to ADMIN user so that only ADMIN user is responsible for creating the other users from the application which will have their respective permissions. For example: Finance user should only view finance tiles launchpad.

Currently, the user details are getting stored in Catalog but the user is not registering to Security portal to access the SAP HANA Cloud based developed custom Application.

[SAP Web-based development workbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vq6eu.jpg)

[Security portal or Security button screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u78Tr.jpg)

Comment: I’m wondering about the term “security portal”.
Could you please post a screenshot of this “security portal”, where you try to grant the roles to user ADMIN?

Comment: When you navigate to SAP Web-based development workbench, the screen that appears, consists of Editor, Catalog, Security, Traces. Navigating back to Users on the left in Security and DB user is selected (SYSTEM in most cases). Using that SYSTEM user, a new Admin user can be created in order to avoid the use of SYSTEM user. So, what all roles need to be granted by SYSTEM user to that Admin User?..

Screenshot uploaded..Please check.. @SAP Fiori Crew

Comment: I think you should create a new role containing at least "USER ADMIN" system privilege and "MONITORING" role and assign it to user “ADMIN”.
I assume you already have seen this docu: [Recommendations for Database Users, Roles, and Privileges](https://help.sap.com/viewer/742945a940f240f4a2a0e39f93d3e2d4/2.0.01/en-US/45955420940c4e80a1379bc7270cead6.html) and [SAP HANA User Management](https://help.sap.com/viewer/b3ee5778bc2e4a089d3299b82ec762a7/2.0.02/en-US/dea55d23bb571014bf25f6ed0d3b2b17.html)

Comment: Yea..I've assigned these roles already but still not working..
Is there anything else which I'm missing?

Comment: `GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA "ABC" TO ABC;`
 i.e. `GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA "SCHEMA_NAME" TO USERNAME;`
Not able to grant select permission to schema, will that be the case that is hindering the creation of users?

Comment: [Here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/6b94445c94ae495c83a19646e7c3fd56/2.0.02/en-US/c0555f0bbb5710148faabb0a6e35c457.html) it says:
“Prerequisites
You have the system privilege USER ADMIN.
You have the privileges required to grant specific privileges and roles to the new user. 
To grant SQL privileges and roles, you must have the privilege and/or role yourself and be authorized to grant it to others. ...

Comment: ... To grant privileges on activated repository objects, you must be authorized to execute certain stored procedures. 
For more information, see Prerequisites for Granting and Revoking Privileges and Roles. If you are integrating SAP HANA database users into a single-sign on (SSO) environment using one or more of the supported mechanisms, 
the necessary infrastructure must be in place and configured.”